# Segfault with Meteor + Passenger + Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, passenger

I have a Meteor app in production with Passenger+Nginx following this guide:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/

I have configured passenger to run multiple node threads with this configuration:

```
   passenger_max_pool_size 8;
   passenger_min_instances 8;
```

The meteor app serves an API REST for a mobile app and my problem is that the API randomly causes an segfault error like this in the syslog:

```
Passenger NodeA[24873]: segfault at 100000007 ip 000022bb101f46ef sp 00007f83f2037218 error 4
Passenger NodeA[18964]: segfault at 100000007 ip 000020339c6746ef sp 00007f79aa78b2f8 error 4
```

The error happens with differents services randomly, for example I have a POST service that stores a picture and 1 of 4 times aprox the nginx logs shows this:

```
[ W 2019-06-18 08:00:56.6081 9877/T9 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 1-122] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ N 2019-06-18 08:00:57.0585 9877/Tc age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1146 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 10466, application /var/www/meteor/bundle (production)
```

Another example:

```
[ W 2019-06-18 08:11:12.2328 9877/Ti age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 6-161] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ W 2019-06-18 08:11:15.1779 9877/T3 age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:102 ]: Process (pid=13735, group=/var/www/meteor/bundle (production)) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
[ N 2019-06-18 08:11:15.1779 9877/T3 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1146 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 13735, application /var/www/meteor/bundle (production)
```

I don't know how to debug this error, the

> Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response

message is supposed to come from passenger when nginx didn't return a response but the nginx log is not showing any exception or anything about this error and the segfault log did not show the line either.

Comment: Does it fail with default pool size and instances?

Comment: Yes, it fails. It is in an EC2 AWS instance by the way. 
I installed & configured it first in a t2.micro free instance for testing purposes and then migrated it to a bigger instance. 
In the t2.micro I tried to reproduce the error but I couldn't, I don't know if it is by the traffic.

Comment: Sounds like it might be running out of memory? have you got a way to monitor memory usage around the time of the segfault?

Comment: Yes, I have monitored the memory but nothing seems wrong, unless there is some memory limit assigned to each node thread or something like that